# Dynamically Assigning value to hyperlink for file Downloads

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

MVC3 VB.NET Razor view Application... I have a view that uses a for each loop to display all the available courses. Next to each of these I would like to place a Html link to download that courses class handout file. Problem is I have not found anything on any forums about assigning the value to the hyperlink dynamically since it will vary with every iteration of the for each loop. I have coded the model to hold the file name associated with each class. Below is a snippet from the view...

```
@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    Dim Handout = Path.Combine((AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "CourseHandouts\") + currentItem.handoutFile1
    @<tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.course_ref)
        </td>
           <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.course_title)
        </td>

        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelitem) currentItem.course_start)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelitem) currentItem.course_end)</td>

        <td id="Actions">

            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "CourseDetails", New With {.id = currentItem.course_id}) 
         </td>
    <a href="@Handout">Course Handout</a>
    </tr>
Next
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I could create a unique download link for each file???

Comment: See my edited code... for the way I am tring to do it... The html link is not working correctly.. The file name appears in it but it does nothing when left clicked... Further right clicking only allows saving of the whole page so the link for the file download is not working correctly... Which is what this is about.. I need for the handouts to all to be able to downloaded for this view by clicking the course handout that the individual would like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the link point to a client-facing URL:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/CourseHandouts/" + currentItem.handoutFile1)">
```

Comment: i figured that was what it was but I was having a lack of coffee to realize the solution.. thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

you also have the much overlooked `@Href()` which can be popped in in place of `@Url.Content()`:

```
<a href="@Href("~/CourseHandouts/" + currentItem.handoutFile1)">Download File</a>
```